# HTML5/High Charts - Truncate xAxis Labels

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Could someone help me truncating the labels on the Highcharts in *Jaspersoft Studio*?

So following the instructions from this link ([How do I format x-axis label in highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838738/how-do-i-format-x-axis-label-in-highcharts)) I have come up with the below:

```
<hc:chartProperty name="xAxis.labels.formatter">
    <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA[function(){return this.value.toString().substring(0, 3)}]]></hc:propertyExpression>
</hc:chartProperty>
```

However this is causing the report to fail.

Has anyone truncated the labels on a highchart through *Studio* before? Could you provide an example on how to do this? I'm doing this on a stacked column chart. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this,

So:
1. In Tools->Options->JasperReports properties add

`com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.function.properties.allowed`

2. Add quotes to expression

`<hc:chartProperty name="xAxis.labels.formatter">
                            <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA["function(){return this.value.toString().substring(0,3)}"]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                        </hc:chartProperty>`